# Problema al intentar usar ncurses con msys2

Tags: c, mingw

estoy intentando usar ncurses con MSYS2 y Mingw64.
El programa que tengo es el siguiente:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
  initscr();                      /* Inicia el modo curses          */
  printw("Hello World !!!");      /* Imprime Hello World            */
  refresh();                      /* Imprimirlo en la pantalla real */
  getch();                        /* Esperar entrada de usuario     */
  endwin();                       /* Terminar el modo curses        */

  return 0;
}
```

Para compilarlo lo que intenté hasta ahora fue:

`gcc -lncursesw -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw pruebas_ncurses.c`

Pero me salen los siguientes errores:

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `__imp_initscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `__imp_printw'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x39): undefined reference to `__imp_wrefresh'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to `__imp_stdscr'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `__imp_wgetch'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\msys64\tmp\ccKbxvO6.o:pruebas_ncurse:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `__imp_endwin'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

¿Alguien sabe que puede estar pasando?

**Edición 1:**

Lo logré compilar usando:

`gcc -o salida -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw pruebas_ncurses.c -lncursesw`

Sin embargo cuando lo voy a ejecutar (usando `./salida.exe`) desde "MSYS2 MINGW 64" me da el error:
`Error opening terminal: xterm.`

Y cuando lo voy a ejecutar desde CMD me da otro error diferente:

"La ejecución de código no puede continuar porque no se encontró libncursesw6.dll. Este problema se puede solucionar reinstalando el programa".

Comment: No será `-lncurses`?

Comment: con -lncurses me sigue dando el mismo error. Parece que en "C:\msys64\mingw64\include" figuran ambos, ncurses y ncursesw. Por lo que acabo de encontrar por ahí "ncursesw is ncurses + Unicode (UTF8) support"

Answer (score 0):

Para compilarlo usando msys2, mingw64 y gcc se puede usar:

`g++ -o hello -IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/ncursesw hello.cpp -lncursesw`

Sin embargo si lo intentas ejecutar usando "./hello.exe" desde mintty te va a dar (probablemente) el siguiente error:

`Error opening terminal: xterm.`

Esto es porque las configuraciones por defecto de msys2, mingw32 y mingw64 tienen cómo objetivo la consola de Windows.

Y [en este documento](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/ncurses-snapshots/blob/620aa00589aecce961ab3876202b3c71188c96e8/README.MinGW)  que habla sobre la librería ncurses ofrecida por mingw dice: "This is work in progress, but it is in an state where **one can see it works at least on the Windows Console**."

Entonces tendría más sentido intentar ejecutar el programa desde cmd.

Ahora bien si ejecutas el programa en CMD es posible que te encuentres el siguiente error:

"La ejecución de código no puede continuar porque no se encontró libncursesw6.dll. Este problema se puede solucionar reinstalando el programa".

En mi caso **creo** que lo resolví agregando al PATH de windows:
"C:\msys64\mingw64\bin". Ya que ahí está "libncursesw6.dll".

Si por la razón que sea querés usar mintty podes usar los siguientes comandos:

```
export TERM=xterm

export TERMINFO=/mingw64/share/terminfo
```

Gran parte de las cosas que digo acá las saqué [de este otro hilo de stackoverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75350336/ncurses-program-using-mingw-w64-fails-with-error-opening-terminal-xterm)